# How do I annotate a Python function to hint that it takes the same arguments as another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Is there any Python type-hinting syntax to state that a function takes the same parameters (and parameter types) as another function? In particular this is useful for wrapping, e.g.,

```py
async def do_stuff(
        param1: str,
        param2: int,
        param3: int = 14,
):
    ...

def run_async_thing(*args, **kwargs):  # <--- What can I put here to say 'takes args like `do_stuff`'?
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(*args, **kwargs))
```

In this case, I would like to add type hinting to the `run_async_thing` function to identify that it expects the same argument types as the `do_stuff` function.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

The primary reason for wanting this is so that my tools (in particular PyCharm/IntellliJ IDEA) can figure out what arguments `run_async_thing` should expect/accept. If it helps with documentation that's a bonus, but this is mainly for tooling.

Comment: Why are you using `*args` and `**kwargs` if you know the arguments have to be a `str` and 2 `int`s?

Comment: Because there's more than just the 3 arguments (this is just example code), and in any case I would prefer to avoid duplication, as it hinders development - when I alter the signature of `do_stuff` I would then need to alter the signature of `run_async_thing` too.

Comment: What also hinders development is looking at a function signature to figure out how it works and only find *args and **kwargs.

Comment: Right, and in that case having it annotated to say "takes parameters like func_x" would help a lot.

Comment: Do you want the annotations for documentation, or for use with tools like `mypy`?

Comment: Mostly for tooling; if it documents the situation well too then that's even better, but comments are easy for documentation

Comment: suggest you put that information into the question proper since its of key importance here.

Answer (score 3):

Define the parameters explicitly. You are unnecessarily generalizing the signature for `run_async_thing`:

```
def run_async_thing(p1: str, p2: int, p3: int):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(p1, p2, p3))
```

More generally, you can have `run_async_thing` take a single tuple (or other object) as an argument. For example:

```
async def do_stuff(t: Tuple[str, int, int]):
    ...

def run_async_thing(args: Tuple[str, int, int]):
   return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(args))
```

The tuple type can be factored out:

```
StuffDoerArgs = Tuple[str, int, int]

async def do_stuff(t: StuffDoerArgs):
    ...

def run_async_thing(args: StuffDoerArgs):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the parameter types and return types. You can then copy the `__annotations__` from one function to the other.

Example:

```
def abc(num: int, name: str) -> list:
    return [num, name]

print(abc.__annotations__)

Output: {'num': <class 'int'>, 'name': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'list'>}
```

Now we create another function:

```
def xyz(num, name):
    return [num, name]

print(xyz.__annotations__)

Output: {}
```

You can just copy over the `__annotations__` output from one to the other.

```
xyz.__annotations__ = abc.__annotations__
```

So now:

```
print(xyz.__annotations__)

Output: {'num': <class 'int'>, 'name': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'list'>}
```

Comment: That might work for documentation, but `mypy` will ignore the annotations.

Comment: Understood. It wasn't clarified in the question (as of now)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem just now, and found out a way that's concise and works in Pylance/Pyright.

In some cases it's not plausible to replicate the other function's signature, as it may be very complex.

The solution to this is to type hint one function as another. Here's an example with the original askers code:

```py
async def do_stuff(
        param1: str,
        param2: int,
        param3: int = 14,
):
    ...

def run_async_thing(*args, **kwargs):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(*args, **kwargs))

run_async_thing: do_stuff = run_async_thing
```

This would be picked up by Pylance/Pyright

[image: A screenshot showing this working]

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately I am using JetBrains tools, and this doesn't help there as of today

Comment: Ha! Thank you so much for this, I was banging my head against a problem for the last two days and this finally solved it :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work in JetBrains or not, but as suggested in a [separate related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031173/type-hinting-for-a-function-wrapping-another-function-accepting-the-same-argume), you can use a decorator with type annotations to achieve this, and since it is decorator function, you could also handle the annotations there for documentation.

```py
import asyncio
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

class Stuff:
    name = 3
    age = 5

T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def wraps(x: Callable[P, Any]):
    def decorator(f: Callable[..., V]) -> Callable[P, V]:
        f.__annotations__ = {**x.__annotations__, "return": f.__annotations__["return"]}
        return f
    return decorator

async def do_stuff(param1: str, param2: int, param3: int = 14) -> Stuff:
    pass

@wraps(do_stuff)
def run_async_thing(*args, **kwargs):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(*args, **kwargs))

result = run_async_thing(param1="hello", param2="world")
```

When I tried this with PyLance, the result is that it picks up that `run_async_thing` accepts the arguments of `do_stuff`, and it also picks up that the return value is a `Stuff` object.

The above uses the `typing_extensions` module, which may not be ideal.  If you want to avoid that and don't care about the return type being accurate, you could just use the whole function as the generic.

```py
def wraps(x: T):
    def decorator(f) -> T:
        f.__annotations__ = x.__annotations__
        return f
    return decorator
```

With this, the return value comes through as being a coroutine, although it is not.

Another thing I've noticed is that setting `f.__annotations__` doesn't seem to do much from what I can tell - at least pydoc still shows the method parameters as defined directly on the function.

Another note (your question didn't as much ask about this) is that there doesn't seem to be a way to annotate a Callable as accepting both parameters from itself as well as from another method that it wraps.  Using `Union[Callable[P, T], Callable[R,T]]` where `P` and `R` are the `ParamSpec` types of the two methods and `T` is the return type of the wrapper seems to get close, except that positional arguments, if any, are off, and keyword args either match one set or the other but not both at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

If you find yourself consistently using the set of parameters for different functions you could consider grouping them with a class-

Instead of

```
async def do_stuff(
        param1: str,
        param2: int,
        param3: int,
):
    ...

def run_async_thing(p1: str, p2: int, p3: int):
    ...
```

You could do

```
class AsyncArgs:
    def __init__(self, p1: str, p2: int, p3: int):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3

    def get_p1(self):
        return self.p1

    def get_p2(self):
        return self.p2

    def get_p3(self):
        return self.p3

async def do_stuff(args: AsyncArgs):
    ...

def run_async_thing(args: AsyncArgs):
    ...
```