# Type hinting for a function wrapping another function, accepting the same arguments

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
def function(a: int, b: str) -> None:
    pass 

def wrapper(extra: int, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    do_something_with_extra(extra)
    function(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there an easy way for wrapper to inherit function()'s type hints without retyping all of them?
Normally I'd write

```
def wrapper(extra: int, a: int, b: str) -> None:
```

But it becomes very verbose with a lot of arguments, and I have to update wrapper() every time I update function()'s arguments, and using `*args, **kwargs` means there won't be proper autocomplete in vscode and other editors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best that you can do is to use a decorator for this purpose, and you can use `Concatenate` and `ParamSpec`. I use python 3.8 and I had to install `typing_extensions` for them.
In the code below, if you type function in VSCode, it will show the int argument but without the "extra" name in front of it.

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec


P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def wrapper(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[int, P], R]:
    def inner(extra, *args, **kwargs):
        print(extra)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return inner

@wrapper
def function(a: int, b: str) -> None:
    print(a, b)
    pass 

# typing function will show 'function: (int, a: int, b: str) -> None'
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking, note that I'm not using a decorator. I'm simply calling the function from inside the wrapper. It could also be a closure, so a decorator there would not be an option.