# How do I "wrap" a Python function without losing type information?

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to provide some higher level logic to a Python function that calls an external library, e.g:

```py
class Example():
  def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return library.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Depending on the result of the Python library, we might want to do different things, e.g:

```py
class Example():
  def my_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      return library.func(*args, **kwargs)
    except LibraryRateLimitError:
      # Simplified version of backoff:
      time.sleep(2)
      return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately, this new function loses *all* typing.  The `library.func` is complex, with dozens of arguments, so I don't want to type it manually.  Is there a way to statically tell the analyser that the higher level function takes in the same arguments as the lower-level one?

Comment: you can write your wrapper as a decorator and use `ParamSpec`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031173/type-hinting-for-a-function-wrapping-another-function-accepting-the-same-argume for more details about how to do that.