statically override function's argument and keep correct type hints and doc-strings
I have a function original with specified arguments, their types and a doc-string.
How can I define a function new that what that it would basically call original but override a argument with some A_DEFAULT value. E.g. new(x) == original(A_DEFAULT, x).
The most important part is that resulting new

should have original signature but without a argument
keep the original doc string
both signature and doc string should be visible from IDE

The goal is to make those kind of partial functions without copying the original doc-strings and signatures explicitly.
Any ideas how it can be done? (even if you have some hacky idea)
import functools


A_DEFAULT  = ...


def original(a: int, b: str):
    "description"
    return a + b


# `new` should have in IDE tooltips and type checks:
# -  __doc__ = "description"
# - signature = (b: int)
# new(x) = original(A_DEFAULT, x)
new = ...



See functools.wraps.

Are you asking how to copy the type hints of original to new, except for the first argument?

What IDE do you use?

@InSync VS Code (Pylance) but the question is not IDE specific as code later may be used in different IDEs.

@Barmar yes. And also copy the doc-string

@CharlesDuffy I think functools.wraps don't help in this case since it's designed to copy the signature entirely.

Why would you want to copy the docstring? Your new function takes 1 less argument, so the docstring would be wrong.

Maybe this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387444/how-do-i-annotate-a-python-function-to-hint-that-it-takes-the-same-arguments-as but removing the annoation for a may be tricky. And I'm not sure if the IDE will understand it statically.

@Barmar "Why would you want to copy the docstring?", - yeah, this is a bit controversial part but in my case arguments are either not described in the doc-string or their description not as important as the rest of the doc-string I'm trying to preserve.

Anyway, the docstring is stored in the __doc__ property of the function, so you can just do new.__doc__ = original.__doc__

@Barmar that was my idea too but it doesn't work statically (though it will work dynamically, for Jupyter, interpreters, etc). Tried it in pylance and pyright, see https://pastebin.com/qRv7Rq5E

Yeah, there are a bunch of solutions for duplicating the signature of another function, but as soon as you start modifying it I think you exceed the ability of static type checking.

Static Typing
The below solution is based on this example here. For the static typing behaviour including the docstring, Concatenate and ParamSpec prove useful:
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

def original(a: int, b: str):
    "description"
    return str(a) + b

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
T = TypeVar("T")
def set_first_arg_default(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R], 
    first_arg_default: T
) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return f(first_arg_default, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

A_DEFAULT = 1
new = set_first_arg_default(original, A_DEFAULT)
print(new("x"))

Static Typing and Runtime
If you also require the docstring and signature to be updated at runtime, the inspect library can be used to modify __signature__. I've separated this example as it makes the solution more complex:
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar
import inspect

def original(a: int, b: str):
    "description"
    return str(a) + b


P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
T = TypeVar("T")
def set_first_arg_default(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R], 
    first_arg_default: T
) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def get_new_signature(
        f: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]
    ) -> inspect.Signature:
        old_sig =  inspect.signature(f)
        params = list(dict(old_sig.parameters).values())
        return old_sig.replace(parameters=params[1:])

    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return f(first_arg_default, *args, **kwargs)
    
    # This section is optional as far as IDEs are concerned
    inner.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    inner.__signature__ = get_new_signature(f) # type: ignore reportFunctionMemberAccess
    return inner

A_DEFAULT = 1
new = set_first_arg_default(original, A_DEFAULT)
print(new("x"))

help(new)


Thank you! Interesting that using same ParamSpec P in both input and returned callables makes IDE to also preserve the doc string, though new.__doc__ is actually None in the first example. Though, to expand on this - any ideas if it's possible to skip in the returned function not the first argument of first n arguments but some n-th argument last n arguments? I guess if it would be possible, it can't be done with Concatenate as it's only supports ParamSpec as it's last argument.

I think in terms of static typing these ideas are still quite in their infancy - as you say the Param spec notation is currently quite limited in it's capabilities. At runtime signatures are more flexible - I made this library a few years ago to allow for dynamic modification in many ways: https://github.com/dreamingspires/Mutate-Function
